# I faced an error while logging in to my SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

[image: This is the error I get during login]

The error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server,but then an error occured during the login process(provider:SSL Provider:0-The specified data could not be decrypted.) (Microsoft SQL Server0

Answer (score 1):

Open **Connect to Server** box and unset **Encrypt connection** option in **Connection Properties** tab.

[image: Disable encrypt connection]

Comment: I tried this my Encryption Connection check box is set to false